# analog supply vs digital supply for microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

what is difference between analog supply and digital supply for microcontroller, i mean if we want to give 5VA and 3.3VD to ADC, then how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to your question is that a large percentage of the MCU is digital logic that runs off the main VDD voltage rail, whether that be 5V or 3.3V or some other lower voltage on some of the newest parts.

On the other hand certain analogue oriented peripherals on the MCU, such as A/D converter, D/A converter, Comparator and Voltage Reference may have the analog portion of their circuits connected up to a separate VAA voltage rail. In some cases the chip will also be designed with a specially designated AGND rail as well. The intent is that a system designer can make the PC board with special voltage regulators and / or filter circuits that supply the MCU with cleaner DC rails for this analog circuitry. Cleaner in the sense that there can be less noise and ripple on these rails.

The digital logic of an MCU and its associated off chip digital interface circuitry can generate a fair amount of noise due to fast switching edges and high current switching. This generated noise can be a killer for the performance of 10-bit or 12-bit A/D and D/A circuits. Similar arguments can apply to comparator and reference circuits.

To try to answer your question regarding how to connect up specific voltages to the analog and digital sections of your MCU is impossible to answer without details of exactly which MCU that you are using. You need to read the part data sheet in detail to see what the manufacturer suggests for connection strategies and voltage ranges allowed.